# How to load DEMs from custom source in Maperitive?

Tags: dem, maperitive

Maperitive has the ability to handle DEM files. I have read that it can handle .hgt files (which is what I have), but how can I load them?

Using set-dem-source complains about some missing xml. Does anyone know what the application expects from me?

The official documentation (http://maperitive.net/docs/Commands/SetDemSource.html) says TODO on the topic of custom dems.

In this forum entry https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=15802 the set-dem-provider command is mentioned, however my version of Maperitive does not have this command.

Answer (score 1):

So after some more research I have found the answer.

Here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/maperitive/dMRtdOO9J3U/discussion and here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/maperitive/bwcmQbsovP8.

1. Download your Data and convert to .hgt
2. Create a new folder 'mydemdata' (or whatever name you want) under [Maperitive Directory]/Cache/Rasters
3. Create a file mydemdata.dem.xml with the following contents

   `<dem>
   <type>srtm3</type>
   </dem>`
4. Load the data using set-dem-source name=mydemdata

Note: For my data I had to replace `srtm3` with `srtm1`. As far as I have seen this is for 3 arcsecond and 1 arcsecond resolution, however I am not sure how to handle other resolutions. So if somebody knows a comment would be helpful.